# Windows Server 2008 is connected to network but Internet Explorer can't browse

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v, internet, internet-explorer

I'm creating a Virtual Machine using Hyper-V with Windows Server 2008. The VM is ok, I can connect all my network and I can ping any address with success. But when I try to browse using the default Internet Explorer, it says something like the server is OK but isn't responding.

I already turned-off the enhanced security system. Is there something else I need to do?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

The windows update isn't working too. Like I said, I can ping google and anything else. If I put the google IP address on the browser, it still doesn't reach it. So, I have no clue.

Comment: I don't profess to understand what you are using the VM for, but a word of advice: in most circles, it is generally considered bad form to browse the Internet directly from a server. There are, of course, exceptions (such as a terminal server), but it's generally better not to expose yourself to the nasties floating around the web and do so from a client machine instead.

Comment: Hi @CosmicOssifrage, thanks for the advice. It's OK because it's a development environment. Here we have to use a VM with Windows Server versions (so, we stay close of the customers). So, it is not a REAL Windows Server. We use it with Visual Studio and all other stuffs. There is no real or powerfull data here.

Comment: Understood. In that case, it's probably acceptable. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just deleted my switch for network connect of Hyper V and created a new one. Used this post as refer

http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/19359-hyper-v-virtual-switch-manager.html